# Turn off TextMate 2.0 snippets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate

Summary: I write Ruby and Ruby on Rails code using TextMate 2.0 (version 2.0-alpha.9515 currently) and I find I'm accidentally triggering the 'snippets' feature.

Sacrilegious though it might be, I currently don't want to use most of TextMate's advanced features - which means I also don't want to have to learn all about them. But I can't seem to avoid triggering the 'snippets' feature which inserts unwanted text into my code. I'd like to be able to turn the feature off entirely. Or failing that I'd like to be able to disable any snippet that's causing me problems - but in order to do that I'd like to be able to quickly find the relevant entry amongst all the many bundles.

To give an example, I happened to have some variables with names like 'serial_if'. If I hit 'tab' after typing the variable name, TextMate would insert the template for an if statement and I couldn't figure out how to stop it happening. I contacted TextMate's support people and was told that in theory the snippet that's firing could be anywhere. To quote: "*We use scopes to determine what bundle items are active at a given time, so items from any bundle could be active and responding to the tab key.*" I did track the problem down with their help (it was in Ruby > Menu Actions > Declarations). But now I'm noticing that if I hit tab after a colon I get ':key => "value",' inserted. And of course since Ruby 1.9, it's common to put a colon at the end of a variable name in order to use a symbol as a hash key. I haven't found the relevant entry for that yet - and it's not ideal to have to make time to go looking for it.

Is there a way to stop all snippets firing in a way that doesn't involve nuking the feature forever? Or is there a way to quickly find which snippet just fired in order to kill it? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable tab triggers (i.e. pressing tab and potentially have a snippet inserted) do:

1. *Edit → Macros → Start Recording* (<kbd>⌥⌘M</kbd>)
2. Press tab (<kbd>⇥</kbd>)
3. *Edit → Macros → Stop Recording* (<kbd>⌥⌘M</kbd>)
4. *Edit → Macros → Save Macro…* (<kbd>⌃⌘M</kbd>)
5. Select a bundle for where to save your macro
6. Set key equivalent to tab (<kbd>⇥</kbd>)
7. Press <kbd>⌘S</kbd> to save the macro.

Now pressing tab (<kbd>⇥</kbd>) executes the macro (that always insert a tab) instead of TextMate’s default behavior.

If you wish to only disable the feature for ruby then set the macro’s *scope selector* to `source.ruby`.

As for how to find which items are inserted, use:

1. *Bundles → Select Bundle Item…* (<kbd>⌃⌘T</kbd>)
2. Enter `if`
3. Press option-return (<kbd>⌥↩</kbd>) to edit the item found

Comment: That's great. Not sure it's quite how TextMate would ideally work but looks like it would really help me out. One wrinkle: I wanted to disable snippets in both the Ruby bundle and the Ruby on Rails bundle, so I recorded two macros and put one in each of those bundles. But when I hit 'tab' I get a popup wanting me to choose which to run. Yet if I didn't put a second macro in Ruby on Rails, the Ruby macro didn't fire in a Ruby on Rails file. So it looks like I'll have to put *one* copy somewhere global (which is fine with me). Any suggestions for where that would be?

Comment: You only need one macro. The scope selector tells TextMate where you want it to be active (not the bundle it is located in). For more info see http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors — in your case, using `source.ruby` would also have it active in Rails (which is `source.ruby.rails`) — you can also leave it blank to have the macro active everywhere.

Comment: I *think* the reason I had problems and seemed to require two macros was that the dratted snippet actually fired when I was recording one of the macros and maybe got incorporated. Or maybe that had nothing to do with it. Either way, I disabled the two macros I'd created (couldn't see how to delete them) and started again and this time it seemed to work. Thanks so much for your help. Not having to choose variable names to appease my editor is a big help.